# Compile a c++ program on PC to communicate with DJI phantom 4 pro

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am trying to receive on my PC(linux mint), a streaming from the camera of a DJI phantom 4 using OpenCV.
The example I am following is : https://developer.dji.com/guidance-sdk/documentation/tutorials/index.html  (I am following the linux part)
I copied the Copy libDJI_guidance.so in /usr/local/lib and I checked, it is there.
The makefile is :

```
#define a compiler
CXX     = g++
#define target name
TARGET  = main
#define dependencies of target 
OBJECTS = main.o DJI_utility.o
#define the Include and Library path
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I../../../include
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,./ -lpthread -lrt -L./ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lDJI_guidance -lusb-1.0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` 

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
main.o : main.cpp DJI_utility.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp DJI_utility.h
DJI_utility.o : DJI_utility.cpp DJI_utility.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c DJI_utility.cpp DJI_utility.h
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.gch *.avi $(TARGET)
```

But when i excute a make in the command line i get:

```
g++ -o main main.o DJI_utility.o -Wl,-rpath,./ -lpthread -lrt -L./ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lDJI_guidance -lusb-1.0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib//libDJI_guidance.so when searching for -lDJI_guidance
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libDJI_guidance.so when searching for -lDJI_guidance
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libDJI_guidance.so when searching for -lDJI_guidance
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lDJI_guidance
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The project is located in:

```
 ~/Documents/studies_SRT/SRT5/TX_drone/Guidance-SDK/demo/guidance_track
```

The output of an ls is:
DJI_guidance.h  DJI_utility.cpp  DJI_utility.h  DJI_utility.h.gch  DJI_utility.o  main.cpp  main.o  Makefile

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you downloaded libraries for the wrong architecture. Perhaps a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Yes this is the problem I checked the library that i took it was 32 bit .. not 64. However i would like to know how did you find out ?

Comment: OK, made this into an actual answer. The error message seemed very familiar. I think at some point I did the same mistake, but wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: OK thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have downloaded library files for the wrong architecture. If you're on a 64-bit system, download the 64-bit version of the libraries.